# Schedule Event in MySQL

Tags: mysql, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have been trying to find this answer for quite some time with no avail. Here is what I have to do. I create the very first record in the `table` below.  Then I would like to schedule an event that is recurrent once a week to insert a new record into this `table`. All I need is this event to do is add a week from the field of the last row in the `table` once a week.

**preferred output (something like this)**

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id |   start    |    end     |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2014-12-04 | 2014-12-11 | <-- Manually Inputed (base dates)
|  2 | 2014-12-11 | 2014-12-18 | <-- SQL Scheduled Events below
|  3 | 2014-12-18 | 2014-12-25 | (Every Thursday :D)
|  4 | 2014-12-25 | 2015-01-01 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

SQL statement so far

```
INSERT INTO `publication_dates` (`id`, `Start`, `End`) VALUES (null,"2014-12-04", DATE_ADD("2014-12-04",INTERVAL +1 WEEK));
```

I haven't created an event for this because I have literally no idea how to get the information from the row before it.  This will help me get over the hurdle I've hit in my laravel project.

Thank you for your time in advance!

**MySQL Systax Error for**

```
DELIMITER &&
CREATE EVENT new_publication
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2014-12-04 00:00:00'
DO BEGIN

INSERT INTO publication_dates (`Start`, `End`) 
VALUES (NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY));

END &&
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [mysql event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) if you let the first row to be created by the event as well.

Start the event on the first date that you want to enter. And the event should run the insert query below.

```
INSERT INTO publication_dates (`start`, `end`) 
VALUES (NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

For events to work, you need to launch the mysql instance with event scheduler on or you can turn it on by running this query:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Then you have to create an event that will run every Thursday, say at midnight.

```
DELIMITER &&
CREATE EVENT run_on_thursdays
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS <starting thursday> ENDS <ending thursday>
do begin

<the insert query from above>

END &&
```

This will enter the first value on the  and keep adding a row every Thursday until the ending Thursday.

Comment: Wow man thanks I will give this a shot but it is definitly insightful.  +1 up'ed

Comment: Says I have an error in syntax for the first part of code

Comment: sorry, i'm missing a bracket, fixing it now.

Comment: Hey Haleeem I am getting syntax error.  I posted the code in my question.  Thank you for your help

Comment: hmmm, i just ran my version of the code with week substituted with minute, and it worked just fine. does the insert query work on its own?

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&&' at line 8 `

Comment: Hey I just got it to work.  I removed the `&&` at the end.  Will this cause issues?

Comment: Its strange that it worked without the delimiter. Honestly, that's a behaviour I haven't encountered before. But I'm glad it worked out for you.

Comment: Yeah I don't really know how it worked either :) Thanks for your help!